# How to get all the distinct options of all the products in Shopify Shop?

Tags: ruby, shopify

It can be done by iterating all the products and then finding the options' name and value. Is there any other way I can fetch all the options name? I am using the [shopify_api](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api) (ruby)

Comment: Can you specify if you're using the shopify gem, or what?

Comment: yes, I am using shopify_api (ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.. you got it right... create a hash with three keys.. option1, option2 and option3, download all your products.. iterate through them, and build up your options where each key points at an array of values... pull the unique ones and you're good. Not much more than 3-4 lines of code and you have all your option names.